# sql server 2005 replication via remote IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, ip

I want to push subscriber using IP address except server name. How can do this? Please give me an example or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [SQL Server Replication Across Domains and the Internet](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/replication_across_internet_p1.aspx).